# Create redux middleware with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I've been trying to setup the `callAPIMiddleware` middleware from the ["Reducing Boilerplate" documentation of redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/reducing-boilerplate) in Typescript and I can't find anything similar online that is up to date. Note that I'm fairly new to Typescript and Redux.

So far I've defined an action:

```
interface ICallAPI extends Action {
  types: {
    request: string;
    success: string;
    failure: string;
  }
  shouldCallAPI: () => boolean;
  callAPI: () => void;
  payload: any;
}
```

And this is my progress on the function:

```
export function callApi({ dispatch, getState }: MiddlewareAPI<?, RootState>): Middleware {
  return (next: ?) => (action: ICallAPI) => {
    dispatch({
      type: action.types.request,
      payload: action.payload
    })

    return action.callAPI().then(
      (response: any) =>
        dispatch({
          type: action.types.success,
          payload: response
        }),
      (error: any) =>
        dispatch({
          type: action.types.failure,
          payload: error
        })
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the correct type at the "?" character and what is Dispatch in this current context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found out the error I was making. Seems like Middleware expects a function taking the MiddlewareAPI as argument. Nothing like a good night of sleep. Here is the updated code:

```
export const CALL_API = 'CALL_API';

export interface CallAPIAction extends Action {
  types: {
    request: string;
    success: string;
    failure: string;
  }
  shouldCallAPI: (state: RootState) => boolean;
  callAPI: () => Promise<any>;
  payload: any;
}

export const callApiMiddleware: Middleware = ({ dispatch, getState }: MiddlewareAPI<Dispatch, RootState>) => (
  (next) => (action: CallAPIAction) => {
    const { types, shouldCallAPI, callAPI, payload, type } = action;

    if (type !== CALL_API) return next(action)

    if (!shouldCallAPI(getState())) return

    dispatch({
      type: types.request,
      payload: payload
    })

    return callAPI().then(
      (response: any) =>
        dispatch({
          type: types.success,
          payload: response
        }),
      (error: any) =>
        dispatch({
          type: types.failure,
          payload: error
        })
    )
  }
)
```